# Get list of Users with Roles without DBContext in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I want to show users in a table with their respective roles (if there are multiple roles assigned). all i got users but role comes empty.

Here is my Model

```
public class AllUsers
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my code:

```
var usersWithRoles = (from user in context.Users
                              select new
                              {
                                  UserId = user.Id,
                                  Username = user.UserName,
                                  Email = user.Email,
                                  RoleNames = (from userRole in user.Roles
                                               join role in context.Roles on userRole.RoleId
                                               equals role.Id
                                               select role.Name).ToList()
                              }).ToList().Select(p => new AllUsers()

                              {
                                  ID = p.UserId,
                                  UserName = p.Username,
                                  Email = p.Email,
                                  Role = string.Join(",", p.RoleNames)
                              });
```

quick help needed,

I tried with join but still no result here is the code

```
(from user in context.Users
                  from userRole in user.Roles
                  join role in context.Roles on userRole.RoleId equals 
                  role.Id
                  select new AllUsers()
                  {
                      ID = user.Id,
                      UserName = user.UserName,
                      Email = user.Email,
                      Role = role.Name
                  }).ToList();
```

Comment: If you have relationships set up correctly you can try something like `RoleNames = user.Roles.Select(ur => ur.Role.Name)`. I this does not work for - please add your entities (`User`, `Role` and `UserRole`)

Comment: Just setup a new asp.net mvc application and it generated all the tables. I applied you code and i got userid and roleid from ur.Role.... I was trying to do it without adding as entities...

Comment: you dont need ToList() in `select role.Name).ToList()`

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework? And which version are you using?
You may try to use Linq expression with `Include()` like `context.Users.Include(c => c.Roles)`. This may helps: https://entityframeworkcore.com/querying-data-loading-eager-lazy#eager-loading

Comment: I tried without ToList() but not working. i am using, i think ASP.NET MVC 5 but i am new to asp.net so i may be wrong....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Include` method, which will join users and Roles together before running your query:

```cs
var usersWithRoles = (from user in context.Users.Include(u => u.Roles)
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     UserId   = user.Id,
                                     Username = user.UserName,
                                     Email    = user.Email,
                                     RoleNames = (from userRole in user.Roles
                                                  join role in context.Roles on userRole.RoleId
                                                      equals role.Id
                                                  select role.Name).ToList()
                                 }).ToList().Select(p => new AllUsers()
                                 {
                                    ID = p.UserId,
                                    UserName = p.Username,
                                    Email = p.Email,
                                    Role = string.Join(",", p.RoleNames)
                                 })
```

Also make sure that in your DBContext `Users` model, you have the collection of `Roles`, like this:

```cs
public class Users {
  // ... other members

  public ICollection<Roles> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Btw, it's worth to mention that with the same logic `Roles` (taking into account the relations Many to One) should also contain a `User`:

```cs
public class Roles {
  // ... other members

  public User User { get; set; }
}
```

---

One side note: it's better to call `ToList()` at the end of your query but not in the middle:

```cs
var usersWithRoles = (...Select).ToList();
```